# Is derived class type to base class type subsumed by user-defined conversion?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Since reading some quotes from the cplusplus standard, I'm confused about converting base class type from derived class type. Does this conversion belong to user-defined conversion?

Cite some quote that make me confused about this:

> [class.conv]/1
>   Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and by conversion functions. These conversions are called user-defined conversions and are used for implicit type conversions...
>
> [class.conv.ctor]/3
>   A non-explicit copy/move constructor ([class.copy]) is a converting constructor.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct Base{
   Base() = default;
   Base(Base const&){}
};
struct Derived:Base{
};
int main(){
   Derived d;
   Base b = d; //from d to b, is this a user-defined conversion? Before reading the standard, I think it's not, but now I'm confused about this.
}
```

So according to these quotes, a derived class type object to base class type belong to a user-defined conversion. If I miss something written in the standard that says Derived class type to Base class type would not belong to user-defined conversion, please correct me.

Comment: I don't see anything you've quoted that says that derived-to-base conversions are user-defined. Copy constructors being considered conversion constructors is irrelevant to the nature of derived-to-base conversions. After all, copy constructors don't do the derived-to-base conversions. So why do you think these two unrelated quotes are related?

Comment: @NicolBolas In the code ` Base b = d;` Base::Base(Base const&) is invocated,It is a copy constructor,and according to these quotes,copy constructor is a converting constructor,so  I think it is

Comment: @NicolBolas [???](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.2) Copy constructors *do* perform the derived-to-base conversions. The code above calls the copy constructor `Base(Base const&)`  to initialize `b` from `d`.

Comment: @jackX: The derived-to-base conversion happened during the initialization of the parameter passed to the copy constructor. The act of calling a copy constructor is not by itself a conversion.

Comment: @NicolBolas  "There is no such standard conversion; this derived-to-base Conversion exists only in the description of implicit conversion sequences"  [[over.best.ics]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.best#over.best.ics-6),

[[over.ics.ref]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.best#over.ics.ref-1),
I think from argument `d` to parameter `Base const&`,It is a `derived-to-base conversions` as you said,But the inovation of `Base::Base(Base const&)` mentioned in standard,it self is a copy construcotr

Comment: @jackX: The invocation of *any* function that takes a `Base const&`, giving it a parameter of type `Derived` will also invoke a derived-to-base conversion. The copy constructor *is not special* in this regard. So why do you think that derived-to-base conversion is user-defined? Why do you think the copy constructor matters to this?

Comment: @NicolBolas  Yes,I agree with you that from argument of type derived-class type to the parameter of base class type,it is a derived-to-base conversions,and the standard define that in the cited link,But according to [class.conv],it says that use the constructor belong to user-defined conversion,**These conversions are called user-defined conversions** in [class.conv]/1

Comment: @jackX: Nowhere does it say or imply that *anything* which calls the constructor is a user-defined conversion. That is, being a conversion constructor does not mean that only a user-defined conversion process can invoke it.

Comment: @NicolBolas How do you interpret that "A non-explicit copy/move constructor ([class.copy]) is a converting constructor" [[class.conv.ctor]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.conv#ctor-3),Note the **converting constructor**

Comment: @NicolBolas  https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.user#4

Comment: @jackX: "*How do you interpret that "A non-explicit copy/move constructor ([class.copy]) is a converting constructor"*" ... I don't understand your question. I would interpret it as exactly what it says. Your problem is that you conflate "converting constructor" with "user-defined conversion". "*timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.user#4*" Nothing has actually *caused* the "user-defined conversion" process to be invoked, so that paragraph is irrelevant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211109/discussion-between-jack-x-and-nicol-bolas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's break down what the standard is saying:

> Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and by conversion functions.

Now, let's pretend we know nothing about what these words mean. This sentence talks about a a concept called "type conversions", but it is specifically talking about "type conversions of class objects". So we're not talking about all type conversions, only a subset of them.

Then it says "can be specified", and it lists several ways they can be specified. Next sentence:

> These conversions are called user-defined conversions

Note that it doesn't say "these constructors" or "these conversion functions". It says "these conversions." Well, the only "conversions" that have been talked about are the subset previously discussed: "type conversions of class objects". And therefore, this sentence can be restated as:

> [type conversions of class objects] are called user-defined conversions.

So, what we can tell from this is that class objects can have type conversions. These conversions can be specified by certain things on the class. And this particular brand of type conversions are called "user-defined conversions".

At no point does the standard say that the constructor *itself* is either a type conversion or a user-defined conversion. Constructors are just one way to specify such a conversion.

Next, we move on to [[class.conv.ctor]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.conv.ctor#1):

> A constructor declared without the function-specifier explicit specifies a conversion from the types of its parameters (if any) to the type of its class. Such a constructor is called a converting constructor.

OK, we now have a definition for "converting constructor". Indeed, given this definition, paragraph 3 (declaring that non-`explicit` copy/move constructors are converting constructors) is redundant; the above definition makes it clear that they are.

Being a "converting constructor" is a property of a constructor. The process of a [user-defined conversion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.user) is spelled out, and it can certainly invoke a "converting constructor". But at no time is it stated or implied that this is the *only* process by which a "converting constructor" can be called.

Therefore, the fact that a copy constructor is a "converting constructor" should not be construed to mean that anything which results in calling a copy constructor is itself a user-defined conversion. User-defined conversions happen when the standard *says* that they happen.

In the example you describe, what happens is defined in [[dcl.init]/17.6.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17.6.2):

> Otherwise, if the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one is chosen through overload resolution. The constructor so selected is called to initialize the object, with the initializer expression or expression-list as its argument(s). If no constructor applies, or the overload resolution is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.

Nowhere in this rule *itself* is it stated that a conversion of any kind is directly performed. What happens is overload resolution on the single-argument constructors of the destination type. The rules of overload resolution can consider a number of conversions as it tries to fit the given argument to the various parameter possibilities in the overload set. But those are generic, associated with any overload resolution of any function call.

That is, the fact that the function chosen just so happens to be considered a "converting constructor" does not mean that a user-defined conversion has caused it to be called.

Comment: @NicoBolas A very detailed answer.It's very wonderful.I have got it,what your mean is that constructors of a class are all called "converting constructor" and only if it is used by user-defined conversion sequence ,then it would be called user-defined conversion,otherwise it is only a simple "converting constructor".and all user-defined conversion the standard have explictly defined in the quote when is is necessary?Do you agree with me ?

Comment: @jackX: You're overcomplicating it. Converting constructors are just a category of *constructor*. The only thing special about them is that user-defined conversion operations will only look at those constructors. That's it; in *every other way*, they're just constructors.

Comment: @NicoBolas yes,I agree with you .In simple,it is a constructor,but at [[over.ics.user]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.user#1)  it also says "If the user-defined conversion is specified by a constructor",so I think if the constructor is used by user-defined conversion sequence,then the specially category of that constructor is called user-defined conversion,otherwise it just a common converting constructor as you said.Is it?

Answer (score 0):

The user-defined conversions are not considered here. The standard lists two cases for copy initialization (of which the syntax `Base b = d;` is one form). They are

[`[dcl.init]/17.16.2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.2)

> Otherwise, if the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, constructors are considered. ...

and

[`[dcl.init]/17.16.3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.3)

> Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversions that can convert from the source type to the destination type ... [are used].

This case, since `Derived` is derived from `Base`, uses the former clause and not the latter. Thus, only the constructors of `Base` are consulted, and not e.g. any `operator Base()` that may be defined in `Derived`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Very well, i've thrown out that paragraph.

Comment: How do you interpret "A conversion of an expression of class type to the same class type is given Exact Match rank, and a conversion of an expression of class type to a base class of that type is given Conversion rank, in spite of the fact that a constructor (i.e., a user-defined conversion function) is called for those cases."  in [[over.ics.user]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.user#4)

Comment: the question itself is that from `d` to `b`,copy constructor of `Base` is called,and the standard says that "A non-explicit copy/move constructor ([class.copy]) is a converting constructor" and "Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and by conversion functions. These conversions are called user-defined conversions" NOTE **user-defined conversions**

Comment: If you have `struct Base { }; struct Derived : Base { }; struct Arg { Arg(Base) { } }; void f(Arg); Derived d;`, then `f(d)` requires a `Base` to be constructed from `d` and then an `Arg` from that `Base`; that is, two constructor calls. Normally, you're only allowed one call to a user-defined conversion function, but I believe that the clause you quoted says that the conversion from `Derived` to `Base` is considered like a Conversion Rank standard conversion instead of taking up the one and only user-defined conversion "slot" you have. That clause doesn't apply in this question, though.

Comment: but the standard actually says "Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and by conversion functions. These conversions are called user-defined conversions" It means the invocation of an constructor is a user-defined conversion,How to interpret that

Comment: @jackX *Some* invocations of the constructor are due to user-defined conversions. Because `Base(Base const&)` exists, there is a user-defined conversion from `Base` to `Base` which involves calling that constructor. The conversion is its own idea, separate from the constructor, but it doesn't really have a name, so we just refer to it as "the user-defined conversion specified by `Base(Base const&)`." That user-defined conversion is not considered here. The constructors are considered directly.

Comment: Do you refer to the invocation of any constructor is not equvalent to user-defined conversion?

Comment: @jackX Not entirely sure what you're saying, but I think yes. There is a call to a constructor that has a user-defined conversion associated with it, but that user-defined conversion is not what is being used and it's not how the language found that constructor.

Comment: In other words ,if the standard does not say it is a user-defined conversion ,then the invocation of constructor is not user-defined conversion ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211110/discussion-between-jack-x-and-htnw).